# How to create and compare JSON values in python lists

Tags: python, json, python-requests

Attempting to build and compare lists of items extracted from JSON REST API, it seems like there is likely an easier way then converting the whole json response to

I have JSON data from a REST API that I would like to extract and compare pairs of data from.  The code shows the two values extracted from the response, but I would like to do this repeatedly and only show values that have not already been returned.

```
>>> response = requests.get('http://192.168.2.3:8081/api/session/wifi', auth=('user', 'pass'))
>>> json_response = response.json()
>>> #parse the json and get list of mac and channels
... for each in json_response['aps']:
...     channel = each['channel']
...     mac = each['mac']
...     print channel, mac
...
11 74:83:c2:1a:d2:74
11 18:e8:29:bb:16:39
11 f0:f2:49:0b:9b:e8
6 c0:7c:d1:b8:14:28
6 84:34:97:b4:0f:a1
11 76:83:c2:1a:d2:74
11 f0:f2:49:e2:2c:e8
1 1a:e8:29:9d:1e:63
11 1a:e8:29:9b:16:39
11 1a:e8:29:9d:1f:16
11 18:e8:29:9d:1f:16
1 18:e8:29:9d:1e:63
```

I was hoping there was an easier way to do this using the JSON requests object.

Here is the source JSON:

```
{
    "aps": [{
            "received": 0,
            "handshake": false,
            "clients": [],
            "vendor": "Ubiquiti Networks Inc.",
            "encryption": "WPA2",
            "hostname": "CoreWireless",
            "authentication": "PSK",
            "wps": {},
            "sent": 1875183,
            "alias": "",
            "mac": "18:e8:29:9d:1e:63",
            "meta": {
                "values": {}
            },
            "frequency": 2412,
            "ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "ipv6": "",
            "rssi": -63,
            "first_seen": "2019-09-18T09:56:09.938447-06:00",
            "cipher": "TKIP",
            "channel": 1,
            "last_seen": "2019-09-18T12:45:50.489350663-06:00"
        }, {
            "received": 0,
            "handshake": false,
            "clients": [],
            "vendor": "",
            "encryption": "WPA2",
            "hostname": "<hidden>",
            "authentication": "PSK",
            "wps": {},
            "sent": 0,
            "alias": "",
            "mac": "1a:e8:29:9b:16:39",
            "meta": {
                "values": {}
            },
            "frequency": 2462,
            "ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "ipv6": "",
            "rssi": -73,
            "first_seen": "2019-09-18T09:56:12.473447-06:00",
            "cipher": "CCMP",
            "channel": 11,
            "last_seen": "2019-09-18T12:45:49.718002705-06:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just implement a cache such as below?

```py
cache = set()
for each in json_response['aps']:
    channel = each['channel']
    mac = each['mac']
    if (channel, mac) not in cache:
        print channel, mac
        cache.add((channel, mac))
```

Comment: This looks like it would do exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` to store unique elements and use below one liner to print non repeating channel, mac pair:

```
print ({(each['channel'], each['mac']) for each in json_response['aps']})
```

Comment: This is an elegant command to get the sets of unique combinations, but I was also looking for a way to store and compare that to the next request to identify only those  channels / mac that have not been seen yet.